# Sending and receiving data between devices in android over wifi connection

Tags: android, networking, wifi, wifi-direct

I want to transmit some data (text) between android devices.
Like zapya or shareIt applications.
I don't want to connect each device to a same modem.
I want just to connect two devices over wifi and send/receive data between them.
How can i implement this in android ?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find what you're looking for here [Wifi P2P Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html)

You can create a peer to peer network between two devices that support it and send arbritrary data between both